# Angular2 Routing : Loading twice

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

I am using Angular2 with routing and my page is showing duplicate content on initial load. Once i click any Link(Page1 or Page2) everything works perfect(there is no more duplicate content). Why am i getting the duplicate content on initial load and what do i need to have it display once only

Screen Shot[image]

index.html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-app>
        Loading...
    </my-app>

</body>
</html>
```

App.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Page1Component } from './Page1/Page1.component';
import { Page2Component } from './Page2/Page2.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,

            RouterModule.forRoot([
                { path: '', component: AppComponent },
                { path: 'Page1', component: Page1Component },
                { path: 'Page2', component: Page2Component }
            ])
        ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, Page1Component, Page2Component],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App.html(this gets loaded during initial request)

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a [routerLink]="['/Page1']">Page1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li><a [routerLink]="['/Page2']">Page2</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="md-col-2"></div>
            <div class="md-col-10"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `AppComponent` shouldn't be part of the routing. It's what holds the root outlet.

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent },
```

What you should do instead for the base path, is decide what component/path should be the default view, then redirect to the path. For instance if the page1 should be the default view, then do

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'page1', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Comment: how can i do this if as default i dont want any navigation router selected?