# Angular 6 Router Repeating HTML

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to achieve the following:

1. I have a `mat-toolbar` component in `app.component.html` that displays the main top navbar of the site. Below the toolbar is `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.
2. When a user navigates to the root at `localhost:4200/` I want the top navbar to be visible and the all components associated with links in the navbar to be rendered under the top navbar.
3. The problem now is that the top navbar is repeated twice when the user navigates to the root. Clicking the links, the repeated navbar is removed and the proper component is rendered under the navbar (which is what I desire without the repeat).

Here is the `app.module.ts`

```
// initialization and module imports
const RootRoutes: Routes = [
 {path: "", redirectTo: "root", pathMatch: "full"},
 {path: "root", component: AppComponent, },
 //{path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
 {path: "fiction", component: FictionDisplayComponent },
 {path: "nonfiction", component: NonFictionDisplayComponent},
 {path: 'poetry', component: PoetryDisplayComponent},
 {path: 'journal', component: JournalDisplayComponent},
 {path: 'letters', component: PersonalLetterDisplayComponent},
 {path: 'jokes', component: JokesDisplayComponent}
];
// NgModule declaration
```

Here is how `app.component.html` is setup:

```
<div class="pure-g rr-main-wrapper">
    <div class="pure-u-5-5 home-top-navbar-wrapper">
        <rr-home-top-navbar></rr-home-top-navbar>
    </div>

</div> 
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is how `home-top-navbar.component.html` is setup:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="home-top-nav">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <img src="./../../assets/imgs/logo2.png" width="200" height="50">
    <mat-nav-list class="home-top-nav">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let route of navbarRoutes">
        <a [routerLink]="[route.url]" class="navbar-link">{{ route.name }}</a>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
```

Now if you notice that there is commented out path, `{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}` where, I tried loading the toolbar separately and have only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `app.component.html`. However, the problem is when I click a link, the page navigates to the corrected component,
the top navbar is no longer visible (which is expected since, other components are not repeating the navbar code).

Is there any way to achieve this without repeating the toolbar twice when a user navigates to the root? Can this be done without copy/pasting the navbar on every page for top level components?

Comment: Going on from what @Benyamin mentioned in his answer about incorrect Routes, do you have an `AppRoutingModule`?

Comment: @mittenspair The solution provided by bunyamicoskuner below actually solved the problem. Thnx for ur reply tho.

Comment: No worries. Awesome that your issue was resolved so quickly!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277700/angular-2-duplicate-header and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198685/angular2-routing-loading-twice

This duplicate header question is a duplicate of a duplicate header. Do you get my duplicate? ;)

Comment: @mittenspair I actually saw that post earlier. Still wanted to clarify with a separate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Duplicate Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277700/angular-2-duplicate-header)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AppComponent` should **not** be part of your `Routes`. It is because, `AppComponent` is the entry point of your app. In `index.html`, you have something like `<rr-app></rr-app>`. If there is a route which navigates to `AppComponent` (the route `root`), Angular will render `AppComponent` within `router-content` which ends up in two `navbar` and nothing else.

From my understanding, you do not need a route `root`.

Change your routing config to following.

```
/* 
 * Removed AppComponent and redirected "/" to "home"
 */
const RootRoutes: Routes = [
 {path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full"},
 {path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
 {path: "fiction", component: FictionDisplayComponent },
 {path: "nonfiction", component: NonFictionDisplayComponent},
 {path: 'poetry', component: PoetryDisplayComponent},
 {path: 'journal', component: JournalDisplayComponent},
 {path: 'letters', component: PersonalLetterDisplayComponent},
 {path: 'jokes', component: JokesDisplayComponent}
];
```

Comment: Nice catch! Aren't the routes usually in a separate constants routing file? Thought something was a bit different.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner That worked as expected. Thnx for the quick reply.